# How to get all lines to have the same X-axis value when editing tooltips GOOGLE CHARTS

Tags: html, charts, google-visualization

I have a line chart where information will be pulled from database. But for now I am just trying to get it to work by hard coding it.

I have edited the tooltip for the line chart, but when I do each line is separate and the x-axis value is duplicated.

so what I want is for the lines to all go to the same x-axis point 2014, 2015. But instead it gets doubled and thus making each line not crossing each other.

**This is how I want it to look:**
[image]

**And here is the code I used:**

```
function drawLineChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Orouke', 'feis nara'],
      ['2014',  1,      4],
      ['2015',  11,      46],
      ['2016',  60,       null],
      ['2017',  10,      5]
    ]);

      // build ticks
      var ticks = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i = i + 15) {
          addTick(i);
      }
      function addTick(i) {
          var place;
          var digit;
          if (i === 0) {
              i = 1;
          }
          digit = i.toString().substr(i.toString().length - 1);
          switch (digit) {
              case '1':
                  place = 'st place';
                  break;

              case '2':
                  place = 'nd place';
                  break;

              case '3':
                  place = 'rd place';
                  break;

              default:
                  place = 'th place';
          }    ticks.push({
              v: i,
              f: i + place
          });
      }

    var options = {
      title: 'Progress Report: Dancer\'s competition placement',
      tooltip: {isHtml: true},
      width: 600,
      height: 550,
      interpolateNulls: true,
      legend: { 
          position: 'bottom' 
      },
      vAxis: { 
          title: 'Competition Placement', 
          direction: -1, 
          gridlines: {count: 10}, 
          ticks: ticks
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

**And when I try to edit the tooltip it looks like this:**

[image]

**and here is the code:**

```
function drawLineChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        ["Year", "Orouke", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Feis Nara", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Garden State Feis", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'},],
          ["2014",  1, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 10-12-2014 Rank: 1st Place", null, "", null, ""],
          ["2015",  11, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 1-12-2015 Rank: 11th Place", null, "", null, ""],
          ["2016",  60, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 8-30-2016 Rank: 60th Place", null, "", null, ""],
          ["2017",  10, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 9-25-2017 Rank: 10th Place", null, "", null, ""],
          ["2014",  null, "", 4, "Feis: Feis Nara Feis Date: 2-1-2014 Rank: 4th Place", null, ""],
          ["2015",  null, "", 46, "Feis: Feis Nara Feis Date: 3-26-2015 Rank: 46th Place", null, ""],
          ["2016",  null, "", null, "", null, ""],
          ["2017",  null, "", 5, "Feis: Feis Nara Feis Date: 1-25-2017 Rank: 5th Place", null, ""],
          ["2014",  null, "", null, "", 12, "Feis: Garden State Feis Date: 5-17-2014 Rank: 12th Place"],
          ["2016",  null, "", null, "", 26, "Feis: Garden State Feis Date: 8-27-2016 Rank: 26th Place"],

    ]);





      // build ticks
  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i = i + 15) {
    addTick(i);
  }
  function addTick(i) {
    var place;
    var digit;
    if (i === 0) {
      i = 1;
    }
    digit = i.toString().substr(i.toString().length - 1);
    switch (digit) {
      case '1':
        place = 'st place';
        break;

      case '2':
        place = 'nd place';
        break;

      case '3':
        place = 'rd place';
        break;

      default:
        place = 'th place';
    }
    ticks.push({
      v: i,
      f: i + place
    });
  }

    var options = {
      title: 'Progress Report',
      tooltip: {isHtml: true},
      //pointSize: 5,
      width: 600,
      height: 550,
      interpolateNulls: true,
      legend: { 
          position: 'bottom' 
      },
      vAxis: { 
          title: 'Competition Placement', 
          direction: -1, 
          gridlines: {count: 10}, 
          ticks: ticks
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using numbers instead of strings for the x-axis values...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["Year", "Orouke", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Feis Nara", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Garden State Feis", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'},],
  [2014,  1, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 10-12-2014 Rank: 1st Place", null, "", null, ""],
  [2015,  11, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 1-12-2015 Rank: 11th Place", null, "", null, ""],
  [2016,  60, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 8-30-2016 Rank: 60th Place", null, "", null, ""],
```

instead of...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["Year", "Orouke", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Feis Nara", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Garden State Feis", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'},],
  ["2014",  1, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 10-12-2014 Rank: 1st Place", null, "", null, ""],
  ["2015",  11, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 1-12-2015 Rank: 11th Place", null, "", null, ""],
  ["2016",  60, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 8-30-2016 Rank: 60th Place", null, "", null, ""],
```

strings on the axis create a discrete axis, vs. numbers a continuous axis,
see --> [discrete vs. continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous)

a discrete axis will repeat values and display in the same order as the data table.

a continuous axis will sort the rows accordingly,
however, a continuous axis may repeat labels as well.
this all depends on the number format.

in this case, the chart doesn't realize we're working with *years*
if we convert to numbers, the default x-axis values might result in...

```
2,014.0, 2,014.5, 2,015.0, 2,015.5, 2,016.0, ...
```

if we change the format to `'0'`, we still get the same number of labels,
but now the decimal is hidden, so we get repeated labels.

```
2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, ...
```

as such, we just provide our own ticks using --> `data.getDistinctValues(0)`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Year", "Orouke", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Feis Nara", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'}, "Garden State Feis", {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'},],
    [2014,  1, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 10-12-2014 Rank: 1st Place", null, "", null, ""],
    [2015,  11, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 1-12-2015 Rank: 11th Place", null, "", null, ""],
    [2016,  60, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 8-30-2016 Rank: 60th Place", null, "", null, ""],
    [2017,  10, "Feis: Orouke Feis Date: 9-25-2017 Rank: 10th Place", null, "", null, ""],
    [2014,  null, "", 4, "Feis: Feis Nara Feis Date: 2-1-2014 Rank: 4th Place", null, ""],
    [2015,  null, "", 46, "Feis: Feis Nara Feis Date: 3-26-2015 Rank: 46th Place", null, ""],
    [2016,  null, "", null, "", null, ""],
    [2017,  null, "", 5, "Feis: Feis Nara Feis Date: 1-25-2017 Rank: 5th Place", null, ""],
    [2014,  null, "", null, "", 12, "Feis: Garden State Feis Date: 5-17-2014 Rank: 12th Place"],
    [2016,  null, "", null, "", 26, "Feis: Garden State Feis Date: 8-27-2016 Rank: 26th Place"],
  ]);

  // build ticks
  var ticks = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 60; i = i + 15) {
    addTick(i);
  }
  function addTick(i) {
    var place;
    var digit;
    if (i === 0) {
      i = 1;
    }
    digit = i.toString().substr(i.toString().length - 1);
    switch (digit) {
      case '1':
        place = 'st place';
        break;

      case '2':
        place = 'nd place';
        break;

      case '3':
        place = 'rd place';
        break;

      default:
        place = 'th place';
    }
    ticks.push({
      v: i,
      f: i + place
    });
  }

  var options = {
    title: 'Progress Report',
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    //pointSize: 5,
    width: 600,
    hAxis: {
      format: '0',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    },
    height: 550,
    interpolateNulls: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Competition Placement',
      direction: -1,
      gridlines: {count: 10},
      ticks: ticks
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="line_chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Most of it went as you said, but data.getDistinctValues(0) is not working for me. When I add it in the options as you suggested the graph no longer appears.

Comment: Nevermind, I must have made a typo because it is working now. This is the second time you've helped me, thanks WhiteHat!